# Rendering pdf using pdf.js on asp.net mvc server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, pdf.js

I am relatively new in asp.net server and I am currently trying to figure out how to use pdf.js to just display a file (with dynamic path) on a page on my server. I have seen it being used as `...../viewer.html?<file_path>`. But since we need to have controllers for every call we make to server which will in turn return a view, am I expected to write a controller that returns viewer.html converted to viewer.cshtml? If that is the case how do I pass the file path that is to be opened.

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#file